# Products and sub categories not loading in npm react store for magento2 connector

Tags: reactjs, magento

I recently configured this react store ( https://github.com/storefront-foundation/magento2-connector ) with my Magento running on the server, I am able to load the home page with categories being loaded from Magento as shown in the picture

[home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8UWm.png)

but when I am clicking on a category it is loading and empty product page

[category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESBfG.png)

also in the cmd, I am getting this error
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6lvg.png)

and sub-categories also showing 404 when clicking on, for example, the subcategory of men->tops

[404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19SN5.png)

can any suggest a solution like in my case categories are loading fine from Magento only?

thanks

Comment: The magento2 connector with react store 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-storefront-magento2-connector

Comment: its hard to read the question. i think a lot of issues are put in images, and the images are not visible.